# What kind of skylight would allow the most light and heat into my home?

Tags: solar-tubes, skylight

I live in Canada. I want to bring in more light as well as heat into the living space. I have a standard 8' ceiling. Are there any products that will allow the heat from the sun into the house as well as the light?

Comment: Note "shop for me" questions are off-topic. You need to ask something more specific so it's clear how to answer your question beyond saying "yes".

Comment: "products that will allow the heat from the sun into the house as well as the light" = Glass?

Answer (score 1):

The bigger the skylight and the clearer the glazing, the more light. In your climate you are likely to lose more heat by conduction than you gain by radiation. You will need to get a skylight with insulating glazing of some sort. This reduces heat lost by conduction but still allows almost as much gain by radiation. The best solar gain is had by orienting the surface towards the winter sun, not the summer sun. At your latitude, this is closer to vertical than is practical for a skylight. A sort of "solar scoop" could be constructed, but you will likely lose more heat from the extra wall area than is gained by the increased angle.